# How to import dependency objects

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, database-administration

I have a dump file which is export of a tablespace. Now I am trying to import one table from dump which is having dependencies like foreign key. how do I import that tables( which I do not know the dependencies), Is there any way to find those dependencies and import them along the table which I am importing now?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using imp (import) then the default is to import constraints along with the table you choose.

To find the constraints (including foreign keys), run this on the source database:

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM DBA_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE
  R_CONSTRAINT_NAME IN
  (SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME
  FROM DBA_CONSTRAINTS
  WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('P','U')
  AND TABLE_NAME IN
  (
  '<table_name>'
  ));
```

If you use dp (datapump) then it is better in choosing the right order of tables to import, eliminating foreign key issues.

With the old imp (import) I used to sometimes disable all foreign keys, then 'enable novalidate' them after import.